# Are representations of (bosonic) Lie groups over Grassmann variables well understood?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, spinors, grassmann-numbers

When one studies representations of (bosonic) Lie groups in physics, whether dealing with spacetime symmetries or gauge symmetries, it is often left implicit whether the representations are over real or complex vector spaces, without acknowledging of course that the representations of an algebra or group can be different over different base fields. A simple example is that the adjoint representation of the Lorentz group is irreducible as a representation over the reals, but reducible when take as a representation over complex vector spaces.

When it comes to spinors, often people wish to treat components of spinors as Grassmann variables - this being the 'classical limit' of the fermion anti-commutation relations. My question is whether or not there has been a rigorous treatment of the representations of semi-simple (bosonic) Lie groups over Grassmann-valued vector spaces.

EDIT:

I suppose the direct analogy I anticipated isn't there. When we allow complex fields, we also allow complex changes of basis. This changes the reducibility of representations, because real Lie algebra elements now can have imaginary components even though the boost/rotation parameter remains real. For Grassmann numbers, it appears that we dont extend the reals as in the complex case, but supercede them. So we dont gain access to a new change of basis like before, where the algebra elements would have Grassmann-valued components while keeping the boost parameters real. Unless I am mistaken and people do work with spinors with "real parts" and "Grassmann parts".

Comment: I'm kinda curious as to why you would suggest that the study of Lie groups is done "without acknowledging of course that the representations of an algebra or group can be different over different base fields".

Comment: Lie group is agnostic about whether spinor is Grassmann-even or odd. It's perfectly fine with spinor being Grassmann valued and Lie group being real/complex valued. I don't see any issue per se. However, if you are talking about Lie group itself being Grassmann/super valued, then please look up any supersymmetry book.

Comment: To clarify your question, let's say you have a Lie group transformation $e^{\epsilon_i T_i}$ acting on a spinor $\psi$, that is $e^{\epsilon_iT_i}\psi$, where $T_i$ is Lie algebra element and $\epsilon_i$ is transformation parameter. Are you talking about $\epsilon_i$ being Grassmann-valued or $\psi$ being Grassmann-valued , or both?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Of course not in mathematics - I simply mean physicists are often extremely loose with identifying the relevant vector space of a representation as real or complex, and pass flippantly between complexifications and real forms, rarely with no consideration as to how the representation theoretic properties change (such as reducibility and compactness). So its not immediately obvious to me that the representations of groups I'm used to will have the same properties when acting on Grassman modules etc.

Comment: @MadMax I'm talking about both options I suppose? At least I'm interested in any of the complexities which arise when we take either fields, Lorentz Transforms, or the elements of the Lie algebra itself, to have Grassman valued components.

Comment: @Craig, if you are talking about transform parameter $\epsilon_i$ being Grassmann valued, then you are squarely in the territory of supersymmetry (or BRST symmetry with fermionic ghost fields in addition to the regular bosonic gauge fields), 'cause a boson can be transformed into a fermion and vice versa.

Comment: Perfect. I will have a look there then. I suppose the actual analogy I want isn't there. When we allow complex fields, we also allow complex changes of basis. This changes the reducibility of representations, because real Lie algebra elements now can have imaginary components even though the boost/rotation parameter remains real. For Grassman numbers, it appears that we dont extend the reals, but supercede them. So we dont gain access to a new change of basis like before, where the algebra elements would have grassman valued components while keeping the boost parameters real.